# In C# how to call a method in a second class from the first class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods

I want to call the Apple method in the Alpha class and the Beet method in the Beta class from main in Program.cs.

I can't understand what I have done wrong in the code below.

Many thanks for looking at this problem!

I have a new project with only three very simple files:

- Program.cs
- Alpha.cs
- Beta.cs

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             // Note: there are red squiggly lines under Apple and Beet  
             // in Visual Studio.
            Apple a = new Apple();            
            Beet b = new Beet();
        }
    }
}
```

**Alpha.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Alpha
    {
        public void Apple()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Alpha class A module");
        }
    }
}
```

**Beta.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class Beta
    {
        public void Beet()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Beta class B module");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Alpha a = new Alpha(); Beta b = new Beta(); a.Apple(); b.Beet();`

Comment: Alpha a = new Alpha(); and Beta b = new Beta();

Comment: `Alpha` and `Beta` are classes. `Apple` and `Beet` are member functions in those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mixed the classes and methods. It should be:

```
Alpha a = new Alpha();
a.Apple();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the objects before you can use their methods.

```
Alpha a = new Alpha();
a.Apple();
Beta b = new Beta();
b.Beet();
```

Answer (score -3):

First option - declare `Alpha` and `Beta` classes as `static` (and methods as well). Than you can call methods in Main function